# Modifica secuencias recursivamente

Tags: c++, recursión

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio de recursividad
https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Modificando-secuencias-recursiv3/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es el codigo que hice

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void cambiaSecuencia(int);
int vect[100];
int n = 0, i = 0 , j = 0, aux = 0, k = 0;
    int main()
    {
        cin>>n;
        k = n;
        for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin>>vect[i];
        }
        
        cambiaSecuencia(n);
        
        for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cout<<vect[i]<<" ";
        }
        return 0;
    }
void cambiaSecuencia(int n)
{
    if(n>=2)
    {
        if(vect[0] % 2 == 0)
        {
            //ordena en forma ascendente la secuencia
            for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
           {
               for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                {
                    if(vect[j]<vect[i])
                    {
                      aux=vect[i];
                      vect[i]=vect[j];
                      vect[j]=aux;

                    }
                }
           }
           cambiaSecuencia(n-1);
        }
         // invertir la secuencia
        if(vect[k-1] % 2 == 0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i<k/2; i++)
            {       
            aux = vect[i];
            vect[i] = vect[n-1-i];
            vect[n-1-i] = aux;
            }
             cambiaSecuencia(n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la salida que me da el código que hice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
he intentado resolverlo de esta manera, pero no da el resultado esperado como el de la plataforma omegaup, debe haber errores lógicos que no estoy encontrando en mi código o puede que esté todo mal, pero ya no tengo idea de como resolverlo, estaré agradecido si pudiesen guiarme un poco para solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que se supone que debería de hacer el código? Sé que por eso pones una referencia, pero el hecho de tener que ir a un sitio externo para consultar información que bien pudiste colocar aquí hace que ayudarte se complique un poco. Te sugiero que incluyas la salida que obtienes con tu código y la salida esperada (la correcta).

Comment: listo ya le añadí mas detalles, gracias